# По нажатию на кнопку выведите в абзац содержимое атрибута href ссылки. Как сделать?

Tags: javascript

По нажатию на кнопку выведите в абзац содержимое атрибута href ссылки. Как сделать?
Пусть у вас есть ссылка в виде тега a, кнопка и абзац. По нажатию на кнопку выведите в абзац содержимое атрибута href ссылки.

Comment: пытаться сделать самому

Comment: что конкретно "не получается"

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="test" id="test_a"></a>
<button class="btn" id="test_btn"></button>
<p id="test_p"></p>

$('button#test_btn').click(function(){
   href = $('a#test_a').attr('href');
   p = $('p#test_p');
   $(p).html(href);
})
```

Comment: это аякс, а мне джаваскрипт

Comment: @Михаил1 Зачем Вы написали человеку аякс, когда ему нужен джаваскрипт?

Comment: Не Ajax, а jquery. Ну как одно из решений поставленной задачи. + подключить jquery по cdn  для различных плагинов всё равно придётся. <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.getElementById('test_btn').addEventListener("click",function() {
      href = document.getElementById('test_a').getAttribute('href');    
      p = document.getElementById('test_p');
      p.innerHTML = href;
  })
```

Comment: можно пожалуйста вместе с хтмл кодом. test_btn что это означает?

Comment: Id шники для конкретной кнопки, ссылки, абзаца, поменяй их на те что тебе нравятся если хочешь, ток и в HTML такие же id проставь если менять решишь. HTML как в первом ответе

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Тег IMG</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a id='image' href="cat.html">Кошки</a></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('test_btn').addEventListener("click",function() {
        href = document.getElementById('test_a').getAttribute('href');
        p = document.getElementById('test_p');
        p.innerHTML = href;
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>